# How can I check what csrf token is my rails controller expecting?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, csrf

My production server is not able to verify the csrf token.
I have added the tag for csrf in the application layout and sending it through headers. 
In my request call I can see the token is included. 
However my rails app is not able verify it.

Is there any way I can check what csrf token is my controller is expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of the code used in ActionController to check for authenticity

```
form_authenticity_token == params[request_forgery_protection_token]
```

`form_authenticity_token` will give you the token your controller is expecting.

Refer to the source code [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4f4fdd643f9d19fbbeeec3ac77674f791c9beffa/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L192)

Comment: controller.form_authenticity_token gives me error that controller variable or method not found, so I removed it and tried only form_authenticity_token and it works!

Comment: I have accepted the answer, however please remove controller, just form_authenticity_token will work.